# Reflexivity and transitivity of nearness in topology

Tags: general-topology

I'm reading Michael Henle's *A Combinatorial Introduction to Topology* where he defines topological spaces and nearness thusly:

> A **topological space** is a set  together with the choice of a class of subsets **N** of  (each of which is called a **neighborhood** of its points) such that
>
> (a) Every point is in some neighborhood.
>
> (b) The intersection of any two neighborhoods of a point contains a neighborhood of that point.
>
> **[...]**
>
> Let  be a topological space. Let A be a subset of  and P be a point of . P is **near** A, written P ← A, if every neighborhood of P contains a point of A.

I'm more familiar with category theory than topology, so I tried to extend nearness to a binary relation between sets so I could use it to define morphisms between subsets of :

*Given A, B ⊆ , say A ← B if ∀ P ∈ A, P ← B*

But then after rereading the normal definition of nearness, I realized that there's no requirement that this binary relation is reflexive or transitive, so this definition is useless for defining a category.

For example, I could define a topological space on ℝ<sup>2</sup> where a neighborhoods of a point are open disks around the *reflection* of that point about the diagonal x=y; that is a neighborhood of (a,b) is { (x,y) | (x - b)<sup>2</sup> + (y - a)<sup>2</sup> < δ<sup>2</sup> }.

In this topological space, my extension on nearness is neither reflexive nor transitive. (a,b) ← { (b,a) }, and (b,a) ← { (a,b) }, but (a,b) ← { (a,b) } only if a = b.

My question is, how often do topological spaces like this come up? Is there a name for topological spaces where the extension of nearness to a binary relationship between sets is non-reflexive and/or non-transitive?

Comment: Of possible relevance is the paragraph beginning with "Note that this notion of being close to $x$ has more structure to it than" in my answer to [Confusion Regarding Munkres's Definition of Basis for a Topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1852072) (see also the paragraph beginning with "One the things that (b) in Theorem 4 does").

Comment: "*I'm more familiar with category theory than topology, so I tried to extend nearness to*" --- This sounds like a "hammer in search of a nail" approach. However, a lot of interesting results in math have been obtained in this way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I talked about this at lunch with a topologist, and I think I was wrong.

I misread the definition - I missed the fact that every neighborhood is a neighborhood of each of its points. That is, for any topological space , a neighborhood A is a neighborhood of P if and only if P ∈ A.

In the usual plane topology, I'd been thinking of the open disc centered at a point as a neighborhood belonging to only the center point, not a neighborhood belonging to all of its points.

My example using ℝ<sup>2</sup> with neighborhoods reflected about x=y is then not a valid topological space.

You can extend nearness to a reflexive and transitive binary relation between subsets of .

Let A, B ⊆ . Say A is **near** B if for all P ∈ A, P is near B.

- *Reflexivity*: ∀ P ∈ A, ∀ neighborhoods X of P, P ∈ X ⇒ ∃ some point of A in X, so P is near A.

  Therefore A is near A.
- *Transitivity*: Suppose ∃ A, B, C ⊆ .

  Consider neighborhood X of P ∈ A.

  If A is near B, then P is near B, so ∃ Q ∈ B s.t. Q ∈ X.
  This means X is also a neighborhood of Q ∈ B.

  If  B is near C, then Q is near C, so ∃ R ∈ C s.t. R ∈ X.

  Therefore P ← C, so A ← B and B ← C implies A ← C.

Comment: $0$ is near $(0,1)$ and $1$ is near $(0,1)$, but $0$ is not near $1$. Nearness in the usual sense is of course not transitive. There's a chain of near places all the way to a far place. Of course this is a different concept but it doesn't seem to me like it should be transitive.

Comment: @MattSamuel nearness of subsets, using my definition above, forms a [Transitive Relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation).  Your example does prove that nearness is not *symmetric*, however.

Comment: I don't think it's true that nearness is antisymmetric (the irrationals and the rationals being a good counterexample), so I suspect nearness is a preorder.