# Is the base for the Sorgenfrey topology unique?

Tags: general-topology

the Sorgenfrey topology is characterised by the base $\mathcal{B} = \{[a,b) \:{:}\: a,b \in \mathbb{R}\}$. However, I would like to know if there exists any other base for the Sorgenfrey topology. My intuition says that there can't be any other as this base defines the Sorgenfrey topology. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: I guess $ \{[a,b):\;a\in\mathbb{R},b\in\mathbb{Q}\}$ would do just as well.

Comment: A base $\mathscr{B} \subsetneq \mathscr{T}$ for a topology $\mathscr{T}$ is never unique since $\mathscr{T}$ is a base for itself.

Comment: I suspect there are $2^{c}$ many bases for the Sorgenfrey topology, and also I suspect this can be proved similarly to [how I proved here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1852127/13130) (see the **Question** paragraph) that there are $2^c$ many bases for the usual topology on ${\mathbb R}.$

Comment: Thank you all for the generous helps !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $D$ is a dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$ (usual topology), like $\mathbb{Q}$ or the irrationals, then

$$\mathcal{B} = \{[a,b): a \in \mathbb{R}, d \in D\}$$

is also a base for the Sorgenfrey topology, as can easily be checked.

Or take all standard countable local bases together:

$$\{[a,a+\frac{1}{n}): a \in \mathbb{R}, n \in \mathbb{N}^+\}$$

etc.

Comment: Thank you for the kind explanation, I greatly appreciate it.