# Examples of a basis for topology T

Tags: general-topology

[image]

Need some help here, so is every smaller collection of open sets a basis for topology? Let's say for example, a topology, (T) which contains the following stuffs: {{empty set},{0},{N}}, where N is a set of natural numbers. Is this also a basis for topology T ?

Comment: For example, the collection of all open intervals in $\mathbb R$ forms a base for the standard topology on $\mathbb R$; every open set can be written as a union of elements of the base

Comment: Not every smaller collection of open sets are a basis; *some* collections of open sets (satisfying certain properties) will be bases for their corresponding topologies. In your example, not, the set $N$ is not a basis for the topology, because it does not satisfy those properties that I am sure your book will introduce you to in short order, after it is done with the introduction.

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1852127/13130) is probably too advanced for you now, but possibly some of the expository parts could be of use to you.

Answer (score 1):

No, not every collection of subsets $\mathcal{B}$ of $X$ can serve as a basis for a topology on $X$. Probably your text will introduce these shortly after this introduction, but in anticipation of those, the following two are necessary and sufficient:

1. $\forall x \in X: \exists B \in \mathcal{B}: x \in B$.
2. $\forall B_1, B_2 \in \mathcal{B}: \forall x \in B_1 \cap B_2: \exists B_3 \in \mathcal{B}: x \in  B_3 \subseteq B_1 \cap B_2$.

The second condition would be easily satisfied if $\mathcal{B}$ is closed under finite intersections (but that is *not* a condition, just an easy way to satisfy it, as we can take $B_3 = B_1 \cap B_2$ in that case). Open intervals in ordered spaces are an example of this, while the balls in a metric space generally will just obey 2, and are not closed under intersections, e.g.

The family $\{\emptyset, \{0\}, \Bbb N\}$ is already a topology on its own, and not generated by a strictly smaller base.