# Is a symmetric premetric space a topological space?

Tags: general-topology

#### Let us recall... the metric

A metric is a function $d$ over the Cartesian product of elements of a set and with a real number as output.
The set and the metric are called a "metric space".
For $d$ it must apply:

1. $d(x,y)\geq 0$  non-negativity or separation axiom
2. $d(x,y)=0\Leftrightarrow x=y$  identity of indiscernibles
3. $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$  symmetry
4. $d(x,y)\leq d(x,z)+d(z,y)$  subadditivity or triangle inequality

#### What I am given... a symmetric premetric

I am given a symmetric [premetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)#Premetrics) $d$, so a function $d: x,y \rightarrow \mathbb R$ for which holds

- $d(x,y)\ge0$
- $x=y \Rightarrow d(x,y)=0$
- $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$,

where $x, y \in X$, where $X$ is a set.
Compared to a metric I am missing the requirements

- $d(x,y)=0 \Rightarrow x=y$
- $d(x,y)\leq d(x,z)+d(z,y)$  subadditivity or triangle inequality

#### Questions:

1. Is the space $(X, d)$ a [topological space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_space)?
2. Is it called "premetric space" or "symmetric premetric space"?

#### Trying to answer the question myself...

The only definition of topological spaces that I get a little bit, is the [one of Felix Hausdorff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_space#Definition_via_neighbourhoods):

1. If N is a neighbourhood of x (i.e., N ∈ N(x)), then x ∈ N. In other words, each point belongs to every one of its neighbourhoods.
2. If N is a subset of X and includes a neighbourhood of x, then N is a neighbourhood of x. I.e., every superset of a neighbourhood of a point x in X is again a neighbourhood of x.
3. The intersection of two neighbourhoods of x is a neighbourhood of x.
4. Any neighbourhood N of x includes a neighbourhood M of x such that N is a neighbourhood of each point of M.

I think that the neighborhoods can be ordered according to $d$ and that for two neighborhoods $N_i$ and $N_j$ all elements of one of them must be completely contained within the other (or vice versa or both).

1. is the case: The "smallest neighborhood" for $x$ would be the set of all $y$ for which $d(x,y)=0$, which contains $x$.
2. is the case due to the ordering.
3. is the case due to the ordering, so the intersection is the "smaller" neighborhood of the two would be the intersection.
4. **is the hardest: I am not sure what $M$ would be, except for $M=\{x\}$. Honestly, I would not be able to answer this differently for an Euclidean metric space either.**

---

## Answer (for myself and whoever is interested)

*Reading Henno Brandsma's answer and discussing with him helped me to get the following answer, that I would like write down, so that I have it in my own words. Maybe it helps others, too.*

First of all, $(X, d)$ is not a topological space, because a topological space is a set with a topology and $d$ is a premetric, not a topology.

As we know from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_space:

> In topology and related branches of mathematics, a topological space may be defined as a set of points, along with a set of neighbourhoods for each point, satisfying a set of axioms relating points and neighbourhoods.

So, since neighborhoods are also sets, the topology is a "set of sets, satisfying specific axioms".

Now, my original thought was, that the $d$ *directly* defines these neighborhoods with, meaning that the set of balls $B_d$, based on $d$, namely

$$
\tau' = \{ B_d(x, r) | x\in X, r\in\mathbb R, r>0 \}
$$

is also not a topology, because it does not fulfill the last condition by Hausdorff. If we are considering the other definition for a topology $\tau$, namely that

> $\tau$ is a collection of subsets of $X$, satisfying that
>
> 1. The empty set and X itself belong to $\tau$.
> 2. Any arbitrary (finite or infinite) union of members of $\tau$ still belongs to $\tau$.
> 3. The intersection of any finite number of members of $\tau$ still belongs to $\tau$.

we see that $\tau'$ does not fulfill the conditions 2 and 3.

Instead, we can say that $\tau'$ is a *base for a topology* $\tau$. We get $\tau$ taking $\tau'$, but all it's elements into the set $\tau$ and *also* all unions and intersections of the elements of $\tau'$. Now, for each element $O$ of $\tau$, we can show what Henno Brandsma showed in his answer and thus show that $\tau$ is a topology and $(X, \tau)$ a topological space.

This topological space $(X, \tau)$ is in fact induced by a premetric space $(X, d)$, but that does not mean, that $(X, d)$ is a topological space, or that $(X, \tau')$ is a topological space. This also answers my question 2. In fact, I found the term *premetric space* in publications.

Comment: Others likely know more specifically about what you're asking than I do, but if you intend to dig into such things more than superficially, then you'll need to read a survey of "generalized metric spaces" and their relation to topological spaces, closure spaces, uniform spaces, quasi-uniform spaces, proximity spaces, and other variations. One good place to look is [**Encyclopedia of General Topology**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0444503552) edited by by K. P. Hart and Jun-iti Nagata and J. E. Vaughan.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro: Since researching these things are not my main work, but I need them for my definitions for my machine learning research, I would say, I am looking for "semi-superficially"... :-D The description of the book suggests that the book might fit the pill especially since it says to not require too much preliminary knowledge. Thank you!

Comment: The book is a bit expensive (but maybe you can get a library copy; I'm thinking of buying it sometime, but thus far it's not been high enough on my list of books to get relative to its cost), but aside from that it appears to very succinctly lay out very specific facts about a great many not-so-well-known topics along with lots of selected bibliographic lists, so for you it might be worth considering (if you can afford it). As for "preliminary knowledge", I think they probably mean something like "not much beyond a standard relatively stiff course that covers most of Willard's text".

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro: What is "Willard's text"?

Comment: You cannot always "order the neighbourhoods of a point by inclusion" (yes, metric spaces have an ordered (by inclusion) *base* of neighbourhoods, which is maybe enough for you, but some spaces don't even have that, if they do it's called a "radial space").

Comment: *What is "Willard's text"* --- [**General Topology**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0486434796) by Stephen W. Willard (1970; Dover reprint 2004), probably the 2nd best known English language topology text (after Munkres' [**Topology**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0131816292); possibly 3rd best known among those who are a bit older due to Kelley's [**General Topology**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0387901256) long reign as the best known text). See [this search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Willard%22+%22Topology%22+site%3Amath.stackexchange.com) for Stack Exchange questions about Willard's text.

Comment: While I'm here, the following lengthy essays of mine might have some expositional aspects in a few places that could be of interest to you now or in the future: [this essay on basis of a topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1852127/13130) (especially the comments just after *1. Basis for a topological* $\ldots,$ and the comments just before *3. Comparing* $\ldots)$ and [this essay on certain types of generalized topological notions](https://mathoverflow.net/a/343400/15780).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual way to define a topology $\mathcal{T}_d$ from a metric-like function $d: X \times X \to \Bbb R$ is to define $B_d(x,r)=\{y \in X: d(x,y) < r\}$ for $x \in X$ and $r>0$.

$O \subseteq X$ is then called open iff $$\forall x \in O: \exists r>0: B_d(x,r) \subseteq O\tag{1}$$

Checking the usual axioms for open sets:

$X$ is open is trivial, for any $x \in X$ we can take $r=1$ (or whatever) to fulfill $(1)$. $\emptyset$ is open because there are no $x$ in it to check $(1)$ on (void truth).

If $O_i, i \in I$ is a family of open sets, then $O=\bigcup_{i \in I}O_i$ is open: if $x \in O$, then for some $i_0 \in I$ we have $x \in O_{i_0}$. As that set is open by $(1)$ we have $r>0$ such that $B_d(x,r) \subseteq O_{i_0}$. Because $O_{i_0} \subseteq O$ (as always for unions) that same $r$ works to fulfil $(1)$ for $O$ and $x$. So $O$ is open.

If $O_1$ and $O_2$ is open, let $x \in O_1 \cap O_2$ be arbitrary. $x \in O_1$ gives us $r_1>0$ such that $B_d(x, r_1) \subseteq O_1$ and $x \in O_2$ gives us $r_2>0$ such that $B_d(x, r_2) \subseteq O_2$. Set $r=\min(r_1,r_2)$ and regardless of any axioms on $d$ we know that $$d(x,y) < r_1 \land d(x,y) < r_2 \iff d(x,y) < r$$ It follows that $$B_d(x,r) \subseteq O_1 \cap O_2$$ and $(1)$ is fulfilled for $x$ and $O_1 \cap O_2$. So $O_1 \cap O_2$ is open.

So this also defines a natural topology for a symmetric premetric $d$.
If $d$ is a full metric, we get the standard metric topology.

Comment: 1. Does that mean that $d(x,y)\ge0$ would have been enough as condition to result in a topological space?
2. Is the open set sort of the equivalent to the neighborhood of Hausdorff?
3. Can you add an explanation using the fourth sentence of Hausdorff. I have a hard time with these open sets...

Comment: @Make42 1. Yes. 2. Yes, this is standard. 3. The 4th axiom of Hausdorff says that every neighbourhood contains an *open* neighbourhood, essentially.

Comment: Regarding 3.: I don't see why this is the case. Let's just assume a Euclidean space. If I make a ball around $x$ (this is my $N$) and then I make the ball smaller (this is my $M$), then I don't see why $N$ would be a neighborhood for every $y\in M$. After all, I cannot make a ball around $y\neq x$ that would become $N$.

Comment: 4. Also, I do not understand how this idea of "open" would translate to typologies of discrete sets...

Comment: @Make42 Topology is not about the typology of discrete sets.. And if you shrink a ball in Euclidean space, the larger ball *is* a neighbourhood of any point in the smaller ball. Where neighbourhood means "set as used in the axioms" (a member of $N(x)$), not "open ball", mind you.

Comment: @Make42 to illustrate said axiom: in $\Bbb R$ (usual topology) $N=[-1,1]$ is a neighbourhood of $0$  (but not of $1$) while $M=[-\frac12, \frac12]$ is another neighbourhood of $0$ such that any $y \in M$ has $N$ as a neighbourhood (we could also have chosen the open neighbourhood $M=(-1,1)$ even).

Comment: The latest examle you gave is what I had in mind in general. The thing I struggle with, is that I would have expected that the borders of each neighborhood of x needs to have the same distance to x. So if I take the point $\frac14$ and (from within $M$) the distance to $-1$ is different than the distance to $1$. I did not think that I can choose neighborhoods completely arbitrary. Otherwise, I feel that the term "neighborhood" becomes meaningless. But maybe I am mistaken somehwere.

Comment: @Make42 neighbourhoods in Hausdorff’s system can be arbitrary supersets of metric balls. No symmetry etc in a general neighbourhood.

Comment: Ok, after more videos ;-) and going back to your answer, I might be getting closer to understand... what you said means that there **must** be more sets in my topology than just the set $A = { B_d(x,r) | x \in X, r \in \mathbb R, r > 0 }$, which is a set of set. $A$ would be all possible balls. But $A$ is a topology, I also need add all the unions and intersections of all these balls to the topology to be a valid topology. Is that right?

Comment: "topological space is defined as a set of points, along with a set of neighbourhoods for each point...", so my idea was that $d$ would be a function that outputs such neighborhoods (plural, since for each different $r$ I would get a different neighborhood) for each $x\in X$. So that is why I wrote my "topological space" as $(X, d)$. However, that would be wrong, because I would be still missing a lot of required sets (unions and intersections). So, from all that follows: I can **use** $d$ to build a topology, but it it **is** not a topology and $(X,d)$ is in fact *not* a topological space.

Comment: Obviously you did not write, that $(X,d)$ (or $(\mathcal O,d)$) is a topological space, but your wrote that $d$ defines a topological space (if I got you right). I just misunderstood first, I guess. Am I on the right track now?

Comment: @Make42 $d$ is a *function* not a *topology*. You can define $\mathcal{N}_x$ for each $x$ as $\{O: \exists r>0: \{y\in X: d(x,y) < r\} \subseteq O\}$ and then you have a set of neighbourhoods for $x$ (at each point) that defines a topological space.

Comment: a) My original $\mathcal O$ and $X$ where supposed to be the same thing. I just originally called it $\mathcal O$ instead of $X$. As far as I understand, your $O$ is not $X$ and thus not my $\mathcal O$ (just to get that out of the way, I will be using your $O$ now ;-)). b) "d is a function, not a topology". Yes, originally I was wrong with that as well. That is why I said that $(X, d)$ is not a topological space - since $d$ is not even a topology.

Comment: What I meant in my previous three posts was that $\tau_1 = \{ B_d(x,r) | x\in X, r\in \mathbb R, r>0 \}$ is also not a topology, because $B_d(x_1, r_1) \cap B_d(x_2, r_2), x_1 \neq x_2$ is no element of $\tau_1$, and that is a requirement for $\tau_1$ to be valid topology. So, $(X,\tau_1)$ is no topological space. Is that right? (Of course, your $\{O : ...\}$ is not $\tau_1$.)

Comment: @Make42 Indeed. But it is a *base* for a topology. Topologies can be defined in many different ways, but in the end it's a collection of open sets. What sets are open can be defined straightaway (as in my answer), via a base, like you just did, or a collection of local bases and many more ways too.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks! Now, I am also starting to understand https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_(topology)

Comment: By the way, why I asked regarding topologies on discrete sets: I was having the Levenshtein distance - which is a full-fledged metric - in mind: Here the $x\in X$ are sequences of discrete symbols and the distances between two $x$ are always integers. According to what I learned, this metric would induce a topology and the sequences are discrete: If we consider $x=$"abc" which distance to $y=$"abb" is 1, there does not exist an object $c$ that is closer to $x$ than $y$. How would you deal with that?