# Pigeonhole principle in terms of measure of sets

Tags: measure-theory, pigeonhole-principle

I'm wondering if this pigeonhole-like statement holds. Let $(S_i)_{i \in N}$ be a countable family of subsets of $[0,1]$ such that each $S_i$ is (either Jordan or Lebesgue) measurable and there is some $\delta$ s.t. each $S_i$ has measure at least $\delta$. Is it true that there is some infinite subset $I \subset N$ s.t $\cap_{i \in I}S_i$ is nontrivial? Would this depend on the measure used/in case this doesn't hold, could additional assumptions on the sets be added to make it true?

Comment: Various such results can be found in [this 13 May 2005 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/xR-j_nLoFQE/m/7n1xXggU4OwJ).

Comment: brilliant! thank you

Comment: Maybe someone could post relevant parts of that sci.math post here, as an answer, so we'd still have it here when/as/if sci.math goes away?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: I'll try to do this in the next day or two, possibly also including some more references, as this is a topic I've been keeping references to as I encounter them (typically by random chance). Somewhat related is [Can all uncountable (but small) families of sets with positive measure have an uncountable subfamily with an intersection of positive measure?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/385017/15780), where about 3 months ago I mentioned one result mentioned that 2005 sci.math post. (However, it seems that I forgot to say what $C > 0$ is used for!)

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: This will take a few more days, as it seems like something worth doing well, like my answers [example 1](https://mathoverflow.net/q/342205/15780) and [example 2](https://mathoverflow.net/q/160395/15780) and [Example 3](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/681893/13130) and [Example 4](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/905487/13130) and [Example 5](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1852127/13130) and [Example 6](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/677927/13130), among others, although I don't anticipate it being as lengthy as some of these (maybe like #5, with 25-35 references appended).

Comment: No worries, @Dave, take your time.