# Subsequence of intervals whose lesbesgue measure is larger than zero

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am trying to figure out a practice problem: Let $I_j$ be intervals in $[0,1]$ whose measure is $> \epsilon > 0$. Show that there is a subsequence $I_{jk}$ such that the measure $L(\cap I_{jk}) >0$.

So far I have shown that the intersection must be non-empty. If it is equal to zero, I assume that it must be a collection of points, but would like any tips/guidance to get me back on track.

Comment: They all have the same positive measure?  So not $L(I_n) = 2^{-n}$ for example?

Comment: This is false as written -- consider any convergent series whose sum is less than one and convert those to consecutive intervals in $[0,1]$  (so the boundaries of these intervals are the partial sums of the series).  It has some hope of being true if "whose measure is ${}>0$" is replaced with "whose measures are ${}> \varepsilon$ for some $\varepsilon > 0$."

Comment: If instead you assume that there is a fixed number $\varepsilon\gt0$ such that all the intervals have length $\gt\varepsilon$, then it's true and quite easy. Cover $[0,1]$ with a finite collection $J_1,\dots,J_N$ of intervals of length $\lt\frac{\varepsilon}3$. Each interval in your sequence must contain one of the intervals $J_i$, and infinitely many of them contain the same one.

Comment: For a counterexample where the $I_n$ are not pairwise disjoint, you can take $I_n = (0, 1/n)$.

Comment: @EricTowers good find, i edited the question

Comment: Of possible relevance (deals with arbitrary measurable sets, not intervals), see the comments to [Pigeonhole principle in terms of measure of sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4153445/13130), especially sci.math post cited (which, as I have time, is being slowly being rewritten, TeX'ed, and expanded for an answer there).