# Difference between definitions of Rudin base vs Munkres basis

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Rudin gives the definition of a base as follows in Exercise 2.23

> A collection $\{V_\alpha\}$ of open subsets of $X$ is said to be a
> base for $X$ if the following is true: for every $x\in X$ and every
> open set $G\subset X$ such that $x\in G$, we have that $x\in
>  V_{\alpha}\subset G$ for some $\alpha$. In other words, every open set
> in $X$ is the union of a sub collection of $V_{\alpha}$

Munkres Topology gives the definition for a basis of a topological space as follows:

> If $X$ is a set, a basis for a topology on $X$ is a collection $\mathcal{B}$ of subsets of $X$ (called basis elements) such that
>
> 1. For each $x\in X$, there is at least one basis element $B$ containing $x$
> 2. If $x$ belongs to the intersection of two basis elements $B_1$ and $B_2$, then there is a basis element $B_3$ containing $x$ such that $B_3\subset B_1 \cap B_2$

Are these two definitions (a base and a basis) equivalent? If so, how can I see that the Munkres's version is equivalent to the Rudin version?

Comment: Munkres definition is about the *basis* **for a topology**, meaning, a collection of subsets of $X$ that should work as a basis for some topology on $X$, in the sense of Rudin's definition.

Comment: See my answer to [Confusion Regarding Munkres's Definition of Basis for a Topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1852127/13130).

Comment: Note theat the commonly accepted term is "base" (as Rudin does), a "basis" is used in algebra mostly. Most papers I've ever read use base.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma: Although I put a note about this near the beginning of the answer I cited, I think I should probably change the term to "base", and change the note to say that I'm using "base" instead of the other OP's term "basis". However, I don't feel up to doing this now, but hopefully I'll see this comment over the next couple of days and one of those times take care of things.